# Is CPU usage for a Java application related to the processsors

Tags: java, performance, cpu-usage

How is the number of processors related to calculation of CPU usage. I have referred from various links regarding CPU usage calculations which says process CPU `time/execution` time. If it is a dual core processor, is it like

```
cpu usage = (process cpu time)/(execution time)*(no. of processors)
```

or

```
cpu usage = (process cpu time)/(execution time)
```

?

Comment: What is "process cpu time" -- reported by what?

Comment: if you are in a linux machine, and say if you execute your code `sh foo.sh`, adding time `time sh foo.sh` will report these:
`real` - which is the wall clock time
`user` - which is the cpu time. Its approximately equal to real time * # of processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to keep things simple. In Java you can get the cpu usage per thread and the total cpu usage.

> total cpu time = thread-1 cpu time + thread-2 cpu time + .. + thread-N cpu time;

I don't think using `* no of processors` is all that useful given you rarely want all your threads to do exactly the same amount of work.

The percentage CPU usage is

> percent cpu usage = 100 * total cpu time/elapse time.

This means that if you see your percentage usage around 100%, you are using about one thread of CPU.  This can mean you application is effectively single threaded and you need to improve how your multi-threading works, i.e. you need more threads or fix the way your current threads behave.  If you see your CPU usage is well less than 100%, it is likely you don't need multiple threads and you want as fewer threads.